# How do we compute the derivative of this function?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $f\in C(U\times [0,M])$ where $U$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$ and $M< \infty$ and consider the following function:

> $h(y)=\frac{1}{\vert \{f(x,y)>0\} \vert} \int_{ \{f(x,y)>0\} }
>  g(s,y)\;ds$

If we assume that $g$ is smooth enough in order for $h$ to be differentiable, then **how do we compute this derivative?**

I suspect the co-area formula should play a crucial role here , but I'm not that much familiar to it so I'd appreciate if somebody could give me a few more details on this computation.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!